# Find by has_many models size

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

I'm developing Rails 2.3.8 Ruby 1.8.7 and PostgreSQL.

When I want to search model which has less than specific size, how to write find conditions?

For example, I want to search Topic which has less than 5 comments.

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :topic
end

Topic.find(:all,:include => :comments, :conditions => [(which has less than 5 comments)])
```

Comment: Will this help? http://lukaszwrobel.pl/blog/sql-having-clause-in-rails-activerecord   You have to use "select as" and "having" together.

Answer (score 0):

Will this solve your problem?

Topic.find(:all, :select => 'topics.*, count(comments.id) AS comment_count', 
                 :joins => 'INNER JOIN comments ON comments.topic_id = topics.id',
                 :group => 'comments.topic_id HAVING count(comments.topic_id) < 5'
           )